# Showing compactness of complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I need to show that for $K>0$, 
$$X=\{f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]\mid |f(x)-f(y)|\leq K|x-y|\  \forall x,y \in [0,1]\}$$
with the metric $d(f,g)=\max|f(x)-g(x)|$ , (supremum metric), is a compact space. 
Using the lemma:
$X$ metric and complete is compact if and only if for any $A$ infinite subset of $X$ and for any $\epsilon>0$  $\exists x,y \in A$ s.t. $d(x,y)<\epsilon$.

I've proved the lemma and that the given $(X,d)$ is complete space.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you learn Ascoli-Arzela theorem?

Comment: no, I didn't...

Comment: Then this one would be quite a hard question for you...... Basically you need to prove the theorem yourselves.

Comment: I shouldn't have said that to deter you from trying to do the question yourselves. This question can be answered using that theorem, but can also be done directly. It would not be easy, but a lot eaiser then proving the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

I like the following "graphical" approach. Given $\epsilon>0$, choose  $m>2/\epsilon$ and $n>Km$; then divide the intervals $[0,1]$ on the vertical and horizontal axes into $m$ and $n$ equal subintervals, respectively.  We now have a rectangular grid consisting of $mn$ rectangles. The set of all rectangles that intersect the graph of $f$ is the "signature" of $f$. Observe that

1. There are only finitely many possible signatures.
2. If two functions $f,g$ have the same signature, then $d(f,g)<\epsilon$.

To prove item 2, it helps to show first that in every column of the grid, the signature can contain at most two rectangles, and those will be adjacent.

Any infinite subset $A$ will contain two functions with the same signature, which yields the result.

---

You can translate all of this into interval notation, without referring to any grids. I just find the graphical interpretation helpful.